# Custom ASPNET Identity one to many relationship using multiple context application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Basically, I want to have a user that can create their own stories.

I have these classes:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string DisplayedName { get; set; }
}

public class Story
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

They are managed on a different context and so as their migration. Something like this.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}

public class IdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
}
```

When I try to add a migration then update them individually, it works fine but when I try to add a collection of stories in my application user.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public string DisplayedName { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}

public class Story
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Content { get; set; }
  public string WrittenById { get; set; }
  public virtual ApplicationUser WrittenBy { get; set; }
}

public class StoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Story>
{
  public StoryMap()
  {
    HasOptional(s => s.WrittenBy)
      .WithMany(s => s.Stories)
      .HasForeignKey(s => s.WrittenById)
      .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  }
}
```

Then do a migration on my `Story` entity using the contenxt of `MyDbContext` it fails saying.

```
Data.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Data.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

But when I try the other way around in which I'll do a migration using the `IdentityContext` it would create a new table of `Story`

For now, what works is merging my contexts. Something like.

```
public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public DbSet<Story> Stories { get; set; }
}
```

But there must be a way of managing them separately, right? Or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Inherited context is the way to go unless you are up for the chore of decoupling identity. Another workaround is to create a copy of the User class that maps to AspNetUser table in your app context that you use to setup relationships.

Comment: @SteveGreene What do you mean by Inherited context? And as for the workaround, can you show some examples for reference since I learn from visual examples.

Comment: @BoyPasmo: "inherited context" just means what you've done at the bottom of your question: you inherit your application context from `IdentityDbContext` so that everything is in one context.

Comment: @SteveGreene: Your "workaround" won't work. If migrations are being used (meaning EF is in control of the database), then if you add a `User` class that maps to the `AspNetUsers` table, Entity Framework will then attempt to create that table again. Either everything will have to go to go the existing database route (meaning the OP will be responsible for managing the database schemas) or there's no way to achieve it.

Comment: Yeah, I lost my reference link, but I did have a proof of concept working that was flakey at best - I believe commenting out some Up() code to fool EF into ignoring the shadow table. I ended up just going with a single context which has been working fine for a couple of years now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't reference entities from one context in another, or that context will attempt to manage those entities as well, resulting in errors about tables already existing. You have two options:

1. If you don't actually *need* two separate contexts (i.e., they're both Code First and you're fine with everything being in one database), then the best and easiest solution is to just merge them as you've done. There's no benefit to having multiple contexts, and as you've seen, there's plenty of detriment. The only good reason to ever use multiple contexts is if you're dealing with additional existing databases.
2. Create a simple column to store the related id (not a foreign key). You lose the optimization of having a true foreign key and the ability to lazy load, but you can still at least somewhat relate things this way. Essentially, you just set this property with the id of the related object in the other context. Then, when you need to retrieve that object, you just issue a query with that other context, utilizing that id. In other words, you just manually fetch the objects.

That's your only options, unfortunately.