# User Identity as Foreign Key in different context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I just started a new EF 6.1 Code-First project.

I'm using Identity 2.0 where the `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext`

```
public class ApplicationDbContext
    : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole,
    string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
    // Add additional items here as needed
}
```

and is the context for an `ApplicationUser` model.

I have another context, `ProfileContext`

```
public class ProfileContext : DbContext
{
    public ProfileContext() : base()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<ProfileContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ProfileContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<Lifestyle> Lifestyles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CountryName> CountryNames { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

which has several tables that require a one-to-one relationship with `ApplicationUser`. A good example is `Lifestyle`:

```
    public class Lifestyle
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Profession { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string TV { get; set; }
    public string HomeMovies { get; set; }
    public string Movies { get; set; }
    public string EducationLevel { get; set; }
    public string ElementarySchool { get; set; }
    public string HighSchool { get; set; }
    public string College { get; set; }
    public string Degree { get; set; }
    public string JewishEducation { get; set; }
    public string IsraelStudy { get; set; }
    public string IsraelSchool { get; set; }
    public string Yeshiva { get; set; }

    public int NativeLanguage { get; set; }
    public int SpokenLanguage { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("NativeLanguage")]
    public Language Language { get; set; }
}
```

But I, predictably, get the error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: Models.Profile.ApplicationUserLogin: : EntityType 'ApplicationUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.Models.Profile.ApplicationUserRole: : EntityType 'ApplicationUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. Lifestyle_ApplicationUser_Target_Lifestyle_ApplicationUser_Source: : The types of all properties in the Dependent Role of a referential constraint must be the same as the corresponding property types in the Principal Role. The type of property 'Id' on entity 'Lifestyle' does not match the type of property 'Id' on entity 'ApplicationUser' in the referential constraint 'Lifestyle_ApplicationUser'. ApplicationUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'ApplicationUserLogins' is based on type 'ApplicationUserLogin' that has no keys defined. ApplicationUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'ApplicationUserRoles' is based on type 'ApplicationUserRole' that has no keys defined.

because `ApplicationUser` is a table from `ApplicationDbContext` while `Lifestyle` is in `ProfileContext`.

Since I'm working with two contexts, and contexts ***do not*** mix in EF, what's the correct way to define a foreign key from any table back to an `ApplicationUser` in the `IdendtityDbContext`? I assume this comes up often and I'm looking for best practices.

Comment: Yeah, that's a common one. Simple solution is to use a single context. See Chris's explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36018140/custom-aspnet-identity-one-to-many-relationship-using-multiple-context-applicati

Comment: Wow. Thanks for finding that Question :) I was going to go with Chris's second option until I saw his first.